# Is it necessary to report the bivariate correlations when reporting logistic regression?

Tags: regression, correlation, logistic, reporting

I am writing up a logistic regression that looks at parenting factors (ie., parental depression, anxiety and stress) as predictors of the presence of a child anxiety disorder diagnosis.

What is the protocol re. reporting the bivariate correlations (accoridng to APA6- or even just generally)? Is it advised to include a table of the correlations before the logistic regression write-up? And if so, should this include the categorical DV- even though such correlations aren't very meaningful?

I have never written up logistic regression and am having trouble finding many examples.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I encourage you to include them even if they only go in an online appendix.  Our transparency should no longer be limited by the space constraints of a journal!  In that spirit, I'd encourage you to consider going further and include a matrix of scatterplots, or grouped box-plots, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check the following papers which discuss how to report findings from logistic regression analysis:

- [Reporting results of a logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14634/reporting-results-of-a-logistic-regression)
- [Recommendations for the Assessment and Reporting of Multivariable Logistic Regression in Transplantation Literature](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2909008/)
- [Logistic regression in the medical literature: Standards for use and reporting, with particular attention to one medical domain](http://weber.ucsd.edu/~mbacci/white/pub_files/hwcv-082.pdf)

From a meta-analytical point of view, it is always useful to report bivariate statistics. So, I always report them (put a table in the appendix), even if some of the variables are dichotomous. However, this also depends on the field you are working in.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure that APA6 makes no recommendation on this.

If this is for a journal, you should check with them. If they have online appendices, then @Bernd 's idea of putting the correlations in an appendix will almost surely work.  If not .... well, in my reading in the social sciences and medicine, I rarely see the correlations reported. Page limits and all that.

If this is for a dissertation, it is almost certainly a good idea to put in the correlations.