# linear and logistic regression

Tags: logistic

how are relationship between coefficient of linear regression and logistic regression (or odds ratio)? I want compare coefficient of linear regression with odds ratios of logistic regression. Is there a relationship between these two coefficent?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by "linear regression"? How, exactly, is it being performed (there are many different ways to apply least-squares regression to a binary response variable) and what precisely is its relationship to the logistic regression you are doing?

Comment: Consider looking at [link](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29325/what-is-the-difference-between-linear-regression-and-logistic-regression)

Answer (score 1):

The two coefficients should be very different numerically (after all, linear and logistic models are very different).

$Y = ax_1 + b$

$a$ = the change in $Y$ correlated with a one-unit change in $x_1$, given that all else is held constant.

$Y = \frac{1}{1+e^{-\beta_0+\beta_1x}}$

$\beta_1$ = the change in the log-odds correlated with a one-unit change in $x_1$, given that all else is held constant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes coefficients will be numerically different but I think coefficient estimates between linear regression and logistic regression should be interpreted relatively in a similar way. I believe the main difference is that coefficients from logistic regression would be on a different scale. For example, if you used a log link then your coefficient estimates will be on a log scale. To get estimates on their original scale you can use information found here https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/14639/108922